# How to return indexes of the filtered values, which equal to num?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

```js
function fMI(num,arr){
    let digit = arr.toString().split('');
    let realDigit = digit.map(Number);
    console.log("Is RealDigit an array: ",Array.isArray(realDigit));
    console.log(realDigit.filter((v,i,a) => (v==num)? i:''));
}

fMI(1,[1, 11, 34, 52, 61]);
```

// Create a function that takes a number and an array of numbers as a parameter // and returns the indices of the numbers of the array which contain the given number // or returns an empty list (if the number is not part of any of the numbers in the array)

Sample output:
// `console.log(findMatchingIndexes(1, [1, 11, 34, 52, 61]));`
// should print: `[0, 1, 4]`

I am struggling to return the indexes of the values from an array.
The code I have written so far takes one number and compares it to the array which the function takes in.
Now, I am at the phase where I want to to return the indexes where the array values equal to the number taken by the function for comparison.

How can I make this work, cause after the filter method, I get only 3 times the number 1, which is not right.

```
function fMI(num:number,arr:number[]){
       let digit = arr.toString().split('');
       let realDigit = digit.map(Number);
       console.log("Is RealDigit an array: ",Array.isArray(realDigit));
       console.log(realDigit.filter((v,i,a) => (v==num)? i:''));
}

fMI(1,[1, 11, 34, 52, 61]);
```

Comment: Oh, now that's what I am confusing. I am a noob. THanks!

Comment: Ehh, sorry. Map isn't good here unless you also filter afterwards. Use .forEach like Thanh Son Nguyen is suggesting. But yeah, with just .filter you cannot return the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## New answer

You can use the string method `includes` like so:

```
function fMI(num: number, arr: number[]) {
  const indexes: number[] = [];
  arr.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (value.toString().includes(num.toString())) {
      indexes.push(index);
    }
  })
  return indexes;
}

fMI(1, [1, 11, 34, 52, 61]); // [0, 1, 4]
```

## Old answer

You can use forEach with a second argument that is the element index. Note that you are specifying `arr` as an array of number, so there's no need to convert them to numbers again.

```
function fMI(num: number, arr: number[]) {
  const indexes: number[] = [];
  arr.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (value === num) {
      indexes.push(index);
    }
  })
  return indexes;
}
```

The 4 lines you have written doesn't help with the logic, that's why I removed it. If you want to know why, leave a comment on this answer and I will reply your questions.

Comment: Ok, so the problem I need to solve, is that when the function takes in an array, it has to compare the given number to the elements DIGITS as well, not only the complete numbers, so that's why I was using `arr.toString().split('');` and `digit.map(Number);`. After comparing I have to find a logic where the function converts the realDigit array back to the original array and writing out the `indexes` of those values which have the given number as part of the array of numbers.

Like, for ex.: 1 can be found in 11 and 61 of the array.

Comment: @CsokánPálAndrás So how are you comparing the number with the elements digits? Can you give the full problem or at least an example of the input and expected result so we can help you?

Comment: Here is the problem description:
//  Create a function that takes a number and an array of numbers as a parameter
//  and returns the indices of the numbers of the array which contain the given number
//  or returns an empty list (if the number is not part of any of the numbers in the array)

Sample output:

// console.log(findMatchingIndexes(1, [1, 11, 34, 52, 61]));
// should print: `[0, 1, 4]`
// console.log(findMatchingIndexes(9, [1, 11, 34, 52, 61]));
// should print: '[]'

Comment: That's better. And do the two lines `let digit = arr.toString().split(''); let realDigit = digit.map(Number);` need to be in the solution or that's just your code?

Comment: These two lines are copied upon search results on Stackoverflow, but I need to write this function from scratch. I was given this problem and an expected output. So, I thought, I should first split all numbers inside the original array, to compare or find the matching numbers, then make a logic, which after joining and numberifying the array gives back teh right indexes of the numbers. Since toString.split() and .map converts the original array into an array, which contains NaN as weel, I thought, if there are numbers between two NaNs, then match the numbers and join and return the index.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a solution for you. In short, a simple approach is to loop through each element, convert each to string then see if that string contains the number that you need to check against (which also needs to be converted to a string).

Comment: No problem. Can you edit your original question to include the original problem/sample output that I asked you to make the question clearer, and mark this as the accepted answer to help other people with the same question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a traditional for loop:

```js
function fMI(num, arr) {
  let result = [];
  let numArr = arr.map(item => Number(item));
  for (var i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {
    if (numArr[i] == num) {
      result.push(i);
    }
  }
  console.log(result);
}

fMI(1, [1, 11, 34, 52, 61]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interesting take:

```js
function fMI(num,arr) {
       return arr
              .map((n) => n.toString().split('')
              .map((m) => parseInt(m)))
              .map((o, i) => o.some((p) => p === num) ? i : null)
              .filter((f) => f !== null);
}

const result = fMI(1,[1, 11, 34, 52, 61]);

console.log(result);
```

First we go through all the numbers in the array, convert them to strings and split them to replace the original numbers with arrays of digits. Then we run those digit arrays through parseInt it convert them to number arrays. Finally we use `.some` to check if any of the digits in the digit array is num and return an array of indexes or nulls which we run through a filter that removes the nulls and finally we return an array of the indexes for where any of the digits of the number is the same as num.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject this method to your array prototype like this:

```
Array.prototype.filterMapIndex = function(expression){
  const indexs = []

    this.filter((newval,index,full)=>{
      if(expression(newval,index,full)) indexs.push(index)
    })
    return indexs
}
```

next, you can use it simply by calling method :

```
let myArray = [1,2,3,4,0,3];

const indexes = myArray.filterMapIndex((val)=>{ return val>0 })
```

```js
Array.prototype.filterMapIndex = function(expression){
  const indexs = []

    this.filter((newval,index,full)=>{
      if(expression(newval,index,full)) indexs.push(index)
    })
    return indexs
}

let myArray = [1,2,3,4,0,3];

const indexes = myArray.filterMapIndex((val)=>{ return val>0 })
console.log(indexes)
```